# ControlP5 doesn't modify inherited variables of plugTo object

Tags: inheritance, processing, control-p5

In the following example B class extends A class, it inherits int a variable.

the cp5 slider is plugged to an instance of a B object, and the assign variable is "a".

```
    import controlP5.*;
    ControlP5 cp5;
    B b;
    void setup()
    {
      size(200,200);
      b = new B();
      cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
      cp5.addSlider("a")
         .setPosition(20,20)
         .setRange(0,255)
         .plugTo(b,"a");
    }

    void draw()
    {
       println(b.a , frameCount);
    }

    class B extends A 
    {
      B()
      {
        super();

      }
    }
    class A 
    {
      int a;
      A()
      {
        a  = 0;
      }
    }
```

the a value printed in console is always 0, so the slider isn't modifying the a variable.

How can I make controlP5 work for the inherited variables of a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short story is that I don't think you're going to get it to work like this.

Looking at [the ControlP5 source](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/controlp5/source-archive.zip), it uses reflection under the hood when you call the `plugTo()` function.

Specifically, it uses the `getDeclaredFields()` function, which only returns the fields in the child class, not any parent classes.

The way I see it, you have three options:

**Stop using inheritance.** ControlP5 wasn't designed to work with inheritance like this. So just go with simple classes and you'll be fine.

**Request this feature.** You could file a feature request for this. But I'm guessing this wouldn't be a high priority, since it's not a typical use case.

**Do it yourself.** ControlP5 is open source. So you could just make the changes yourself. Or you could write a simple workaround, maybe a different class with a function that maps to the child class somehow.